# What are the mechanical differences between Fantasy AGE 1st and 2nd editions?

Tags: edition-comparison, age-system, fantasy-age

I own the Fantasy AGE 1st edition book and the Dragon AGE book as well. I'm interested in taking a look in the 2nd AGE edition, but from my brief research, there weren't many significant changes (in terms of mechanics) from the original first edition (the so called "HP bloat" is apparently still a thing).

So, what summarizes the biggest differences between Fantasy AGE 1st and 2nd editions?